# Compress and decompress utf8 string with brotli

Tags: node.js, brotli

I'm trying to write compress and decompress a JSON string, but the decompression always fails with:

```
Error: Decompression failed
    at BrotliDecoder.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:170:17) {
  errno: -6,
  code: 'ERR_CL_SPACE'
}
```

I can't send the buffer returned by the compressor, because I need to send the compressed string through an HTTP response to get it back.

Moreover, if I use `base64` as format, all work but the string output is bigger than the simple `JSON.stringify`, so I would avoid it.

My code:

```js
const zlib = require('zlib')

function compress (json) {
  zlib.brotliCompress(JSON.stringify(json), {
    params: {
      [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_MODE]: zlib.constants.BROTLI_MODE_TEXT
    }
  }, (err, data) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
    console.log('-------------------------------')
    decompress(Buffer.from(data.toString('utf8'), 'utf8'))
  })
}

function decompress (str) {
  zlib.brotliDecompress(str, (err, data) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
  })
}

const obj = {
  wt: '5de52e98aa54253147060a01',
  ex: ['b9ac4a6b-2e72-4bf3-abd5-debf2ece4ba4']
}
compress(obj)
```

Are there any params to get a valid utf8 string output from the compression?

Comment: Maybe this abstraction will help you. Hope it helps. https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have to use base64 for sending data over the wire in any case, this will result is a size penalty of ~37%. This might actually be more efficient than sending UTF8 since many of the bytes will require a multi-byte encoding (when sending binary data).

In any case, compression and decompression work when we pass our compressed data as base64.

I believe the reason it was not working with UTF8 is that converting a buffer to utf8 and back again is not always reversible, that is you don't necessarily get the same result back (try encoding random data to utf8 and back again!)

```
const zlib = require('zlib')

// Encode the buffer in base 64. UCS2 will work, but UTF8 will not.
const encoding = "base64";

function compress (json) {
  zlib.brotliCompress(JSON.stringify(json), {
    params: {
      [zlib.constants.BROTLI_PARAM_MODE]: zlib.constants.BROTLI_MODE_TEXT
    }
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("brotliCompress: An error occurred:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Compressed data:", data.toString("base64"));
      console.log('-------------------------------')
      decompress(data.toString(encoding), encoding);
    }
  })
}

function decompress (encodedData, encoding) {
  const compressedData = Buffer.from(encodedData, encoding);
  zlib.brotliDecompress(compressedData, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("brotliDecompress: An error occurred:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Decompressed data:", data.toString("utf8"));
    }
  });
}

const obj = {
  wt: '5de52e98aa54253147060a01',
  ex: ['b9ac4a6b-2e72-4bf3-abd5-debf2ece4ba4']
}

compress(obj);
```

And to show Buffer.from(data.toString("utf8"), "utf8") is not always reversible:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const data = crypto.randomBytes(100);

console.log("Bytes (base64):", data .toString("base64"));

const encoding = "utf8";
const dataUtf8 = data.toString(encoding);
const decoded = Buffer.from(dataUtf8, encoding);
console.log("Bytes (base64 decoded):", decoded.toString("base64"));
```

You'll see the round trip results in a different buffer.